Why can't I save a Google Colab sheet shared with me?
Someone shared with me a Google Colab sheet; I got an email saying that he invited me to edit an item called filename.ipynb. Indeed, I can edit this file, but when I click "Save", I get an error message: "Cannot save changes. You do not have permission to save this notebook. To keep your changes, make a copy of the notebook.".
What should I or my colleague do so that both of us can save the same notebook?


Google Colab sheet?  I think you are referring to Google Colab notebook. Is this a GitHub Notebook? https://github.com/googlecolab/colabtools/issues/2518 or a Google Drive Notebook
